# How to extract all lines from FileB that start with string of one of FileA's lines in bash?

Tags: bash, perl

(Question in title)

For example:

FileA:

```
this is a
that was a
```

File B:

```
that was a school
hi, you should ignore me
this is a example
that was a sample
...
```

What we want is a file containing lines 1,3,4,(...) of File B in a third file. Any solutions with just bash commands? Answers using command line "Perl" (if necessary) can also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{arr["^" $1]; next} {for (line in arr) if ($0 ~ line) {print; break}}' fileA fileB
that was a school
this is a example
that was a sample
```

First we read `fileA` and build an array with `^` (line start) concatenated with each line of `fileA`. Then while going through `fileB` we just loop through `arr` and print whatever lines matched.

Comment: what does the tilde("~") in the if condition exactly check for?

Comment: `~` operator evaluates regex contained in variable `line` against `$0` (current record)

Answer (score 1):

Using command line Perl:

```
$ perl -ne '
    BEGIN {
        local @ARGV = shift;
        $pat = join "|", map {chomp; quotemeta} <>;
    }
    print if /$pat/
    ' filea fileb
```

Outputs:

```
that was a school
this is a example
that was a sample
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl scripting:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($file1, $file2) = qw(file1.txt file2.txt);

open my $fh1, '<', $file1 or die "Can't open $file1: $!";
open my $fh2, '<', $file2 or die "Can't open $file2: $!";

my @compline = <$fh2>;
chomp @compline;

while (<$fh1>)
{
    chomp $_;
    foreach my $line (@compline)
    {
        if ($line =~ m/^$_/)
        {
            print "$line\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
this is a example
that was a school
that was a sample
```